# Vue - Export b-table to excel file?

Tags: excel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using a `b-table` with `fields` and `items`. The data comes from an array which is stored in an object like this:

```
<b-table  :fields="visibleFields"
          :items="object.array"    
>
```

Is there an easy way to export and download this data to an excel file with proper formatting like it is shown in the table?

Comment: a simple javascript framework can export your JSON data to an excel file without having to do anything with the table, like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel